# How can I check student attendance in recurring google meet's?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom, time-and-attendance

I want to check the students attendance for all google classroom courses. As the meeting_code will be the same for each course (recurring), how can I figure out the attendance for each meeting?  Which parameter can help me to solve that? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, you can if you are an admin

- From the user interface, go to the [Admin console](https://admin.google.com/) and go to `Reports -> Audit log -> Google Meet`. You can filter the results by start time, user name etc.
- In Apps Script you need to [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) and use the [Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) [Admin Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/get-start/getting-started).
- More specific, you need to use the method [Activities:list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list), specifying the student of itnerest as `userKey` and `meet` as `applicationName`
- You can filter by different parameters as specified for the [Google Meet Audit Activity Events](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/meet), like startTime of the meeting, or e.g.
  `duration_seconds` whihc not only allows you to estimate either a student participated, but also for how long he did.
- I recommend you to test the request with the `Try this API` feature before implementing it into Apps Script

Comment: Thank you!   The Google meet activity events will help me.